# Linking Eclipe projects together using 'Deployment Assembly' and 'Build Path' options

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have a simple java project with this basic structure:

- IncludeMe

  - src
  - deploy
  - siteSpecific
    -> site1
    -> site2
    -> etc...

I also have another project which I check out as a Dynamic Web project.
 
I add it to a tomcat7 instance and run it locally on my machine.

- MainWebApp

  - src
  - deploy
  - WebContent
    -> resources
    -> templates
    -> etc...

What I need is to include the 'siteSpecific' folder from the 'IncludeMe' project under the 'WebContent' directory in the 'MainWebApp' project.

So if I make a change to files under 'IncludeMe->siteSpecific', they are automatically picked up and applied by my MainWebApp under 'MainWebApp->siteSpecific' i.e. I do bot want to have to manually copy the contents between the two separate projects.

I currently do the following with no luck:
 - Open 'properties' of 'IncludeMe' and go to 'Deployment Assembly'
 - Select 'Add' and choose the 'SiteSpecific' folder.
 - Source then reads '/siteSpecific' and I adjust the deploy path to be 'siteSpecific'
 - Open 'properties' of 'MainWebApp' and go to 'Java Build Path'
 - Go to 'projects' tab and add the 'IncludeMe' project.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7 by the way.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky solution but the only one I found when I needed something like this.
The trick is to link external source folder and then use it in "deployment assembly"

Do the following:

1. Right click on Your webapplication project (MainWebApp)
2. Build path
3. Link source
4. Variables (Here we will add variable that points to our external project, relative to our current project)
5. New (add something like: "${PROJECT_LOC}..\IncludeMe" in "Location" and some name for new variable)
6. OK
7. Extend (You should extend variable You've created on prev. step).
8. Pick right folder and press OK.
9. Next.
10. Add exclusion pattern to prevent eclipse from building anything from that folder.
11. Finish

After this dancing You should be able to see linked folder in "deployment assembly"...